# Why am I experiencing sound drop outs with my audio interface?

Tags: latency, steinberg, windows-10

I am using Steinberg UR22 as my audio interface, my operating system is Windows 10 and I installed the latest drivers from Steinberg's site. So I am experiencing these sort of lags or drop outs with sound when I am watching a movie, listening music etc... After I disable network adapter through which the internet connection goes, the problem seems to disappear. However this isn't really a completely viable solution since always disabling my network adapters is quite inconvenient. And what if I want to listen something using my internet connection (like youtube) then this solution just doesn't cut it. 
So is there any other way to solve this so I wouldn't need to disable my adapters, like changing priorities of network adapters or audio card, or anything else really...

Thanks

Comment: What are your computer specs?

Comment: System:
CPU: Intel Core i5 4670
Mainboard: Asus Gryphon Z87
RAM: 8GB DDR3
Graphics: Nvidia GeForce GTX 770
@DoritoStyle

Comment: Try unplugging power adapter to laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I own the UR22 mk2 and had experienced similar problem before updating drivers (win7 64bit).

If it's correctly plugged into a USB 2 port (usb 3 is buggy on audio interfaces) It can really be only a driver issue or incompatibility and the best course of action would be to directly contact Steinberg or use their suport forums.